# Codeigniter route issue. Calling different controller functions depends on passed parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

So, this is my controller :

```
class Catalog extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        echo "Catalog";
    }

    function view_category($category_slug)
    {
        echo "category_slug = ".$category_slug;
    }

    function view_brand($category_slug, $brand_slug)
    {
        echo "category_slug = ".$category_slug;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "brand_slug = ".$brand_slug;
    }

    function view_product($category_slug, $brand_slug, $product_slug)
    {
        echo "category_slug = ".$category_slug;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "brand_slug = ".$brand_slug;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "product_slug = ".$product_slug;
    }
}
```

And this is my routes.php:

```
$route['catalog/(:any)'] = 'catalog/view_category/$1';
$route['catalog/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'catalog/view_brand/$1/$2';
$route['catalog/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'catalog/view_product/$1/$2/$3';
```

But it doesn't matter how many parameters I pass - it always call `view_category` function. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work since the mandatory part (i.e controller name) is same for all the 3 routes, and any number of parameter after **`catalog/`** will **satisfy** the **first route**.

A solution can be (untested) reverse the order of your route (i.e number of parameters in descending order) as below. Check if it works -

```
$route['catalog/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'catalog/view_product/$1/$2/$3';
$route['catalog/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'catalog/view_brand/$1/$2';
$route['catalog/(:any)'] = 'catalog/view_category/$1';
```